# Expose specific file in a docker-compose named volume

Tags: docker-compose

This is a named volume (shared between multiple apps, so its neater than a bind mount):

```
foo:
  image: foo:latest
  volumes:
    foo_data:/etc/foo:ro

volumes:
  foo:
```

Lets say I want to expose a single file:

```
foo_data/etc/foo/bar.conf:/etc/foo/bar.conf:ro
```

Obviously that syntax is incorrect.

Is there a way to do this without resorting to bind mounts?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible without using a bind mount. You can specify which folder is referenced by the named volume however you still are mounting the entire folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible without using a bind mount.

You would be able to specify which folder is referenced by the named volume however you are still mounting the entire folder.